# Transforming findall regex to finditer

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have following regex

```
'\D*(\d{13,19})\D*'
```

I would like to extract number from following text:

```
Data:
4532394639182605   sadada 4716759060363635 assasasas
  dsdsd 4539072249615668 jdhsjhdj
ABCD
```

When I use this regexp by calling:

```
regex = re.compile('\D*(\d{13,19})\D*')
a = regex.finditer(text)
b = regex.findall(text) #Yield correct result
```

Results are different- I want result from `findall`. I know that `finditer` match group. But how transform my findall regex to finditer regex?

I need this same result using `finditer` like in case use `findall`.

**tl;dr**

I want extract numbers not other characters.

Comment: `finditer` returns an iterator which is not the same as a list. Do you get different results when you iterate over `a` and `b`?

Comment: Only things that interest me is output- I want extract Number. Yes result is different

Comment: @user902691 Your question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve? Please include full context in the question. It doesn't makes sense that you want `finditer` to behave like `findall`.

Comment: @MYGz I want extract only numbers from text using `finditer`. I need change my regex current regex working like charm only in `findall`.

Comment: @user902691 `finditer` will also work like charm, just iterate over it. `[x.group(0) for x in a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`finditer` returns match objects from which the groups can be extracted with the `.group` method. This is how one usually works with regexes anyway, it's unusual that `findall` directly returns strings or tuples with the groups.

```
import re

text = '''Data:
4532394639182605   sadada 4716759060363635 assasasas
  dsdsd 4539072249615668 jdhsjhdj
ABCD'''

regex = re.compile('\D*(\d{13,19})\D*')
for match in regex.finditer(text):
    print(match.group(1))
```